# javascript promise schedule multiple function

Tags: javascript, promise

How to use promise schedule multiple function , should I have to make it like `2` way nest the callback?
on serverside I use `nodejs` and `co` make generateor,
then make it looks like below

```
co(function *() {
  yield q1();
  yield q2();
  yield q3();
 ...
```

Is there some similar way syntax with promise ?

```
var q1 = function() {
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      fulfill(console.log('q1'));
    }, 100);

  });
};

var q2 = function() {
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      fulfill(console.log('q2'));
    }, 100);

  });
};

var q3 = function() {
console.log("done!");
};
```

1

```
q1().then(function() {
  q2();
}).then(function() {
  q3();
});
```

2

```
q1().then(function() {
  q2().then(function() {
    q3();
  });
});
```

Comment: On the serverside with co and generator syntax, you are using promises already? Why is that not satisfying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return the promise from the then callback like

```js
var q1 = function() {
  return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      snippet.log('q1')
      fulfill();
    }, 1000);

  });
};

var q2 = function() {
  return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      snippet.log('q2')
      fulfill();
    }, 1000);

  });
};

var q3 = function() {
  snippet.log("done!");
};

q1().then(function() {
  return q2();
}).then(function() {
  q3();
});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

with the code you've got, you can simply do this

```
q1().then(q2).then(q3);
```